# Geolocation Heading API not actually measuring heading?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm trying to measure a users heading and using the data to rotate a compass image I've made. It should result in the image continuously pointing north so when the user moves their phone the image moves with it. However the heading value is jumping by a large amount completely on its own, like I put my phone down and the heading is moving on its own by a huge amount. I downloaded a compass app on my phone (which is what I am testing it with) and the compass is fine.

this is how I'm putting into my html

```
<div id="compass">
  <img id="compassIMG" src="Morgsimages/compassIcon.png">
</div>
<div id="compassInfo"></div>
```

and this is my javascript

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
        let heading = position.coords.heading;
        var compass = document.getElementById('compass');
        var info = document.getElementById('compassInfo');

        info.textContent = 'Heading: '+heading;
        compass.style.transform = `rotate(${heading}deg)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it depends from the device, `coords.heading`. It will returns null if this information is not available.

According with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates/heading, "If the device is not able to provide heading information, this value is null."

Answer (score 0):

I leave this here because I wasted a full day with the same problem.
You are looking into the wrong API for getting the Orientation of the phone. The heading attribute in the geolocation is not the compas orientation but a direction calculated based on the movement of the phone. So if you are standing still heading is null. As soon you as you are moving the heading points into the direction of your movement. See this docu: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates/heading

What you are looking for is the "deviceorientation" event. For iOS/Safari you have to manually request the feature first.
(This is Typescript code)

```html
const isIOS = !(
    navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) &&
    navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/)
);
if (isIOS) {
    (DeviceOrientationEvent as any).requestPermission()
        .then((response: any) => {
            if (response === "granted") {
                window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.receivedNewHeading, true);
            } else {
                alert("has to be allowed!");
            }
        })
        .catch(() => alert("not supported"));
} else {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", this.receivedNewHeading, true);
}
```